# Remove all empty values in container X++

Tags: axapta, x++

Fast search in the google did not give me any results.

Here is what I think about:

```
for(i = 1; i <= conlen(A); i++)
{
    if(!IsNullOrEmpty(conPeek(A,i))
    {
        B += conPeek(A,i);
    }
}
```

I just want to remove all empty values from my container.

But I don't have **IsNullOrEmpty** function and maybe I'm implementing the wheel. Is there some function in AX that could clean the container from empty values?

If Not, what is the best practice for this?

Thank's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AX empty string evaluates as *false*.

Just use `if (conPeek(A, i))`.

```cs
for (i = 1; i <= conlen(A); i++)
{
    if (conPeek(A, i))
    {
        B += conPeek(A,i);
    }
}
```

Comment: So there is no built-in functionality for cleaning empty values?

Comment: @Ashur451 no, there isn't.

Comment: Beware that the above will remove 0 (zero) as well, it may not be a problem in your scenario.